# dmd linker (OPTLINK) gives Error 42: Symbol Undefined when using extern

Tags: d, dmd

Linking the following two files gives me a link-error:

#### a.d:

```
import std.stdio;

extern string test ();

void main() {
    writeln(test());
    readln();
}
```

#### b.d:

```
string test () {
    return "hello";
}
```

---

the error I get is:

```
Error 42: Symbol Undefined _D1a4testFZAya`

---errorlevel 1
```

What is wrong ?

### __*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*_

## Edit: this is the right way to do it:

#### a.d:

```
import std.stdio;
import b;

void main() {
   writeln("some_var from Module b: \"", b.some_var, "\"");
}
```

#### b.d:

```
public string some_var = "Hello, world!";

//you can also use static module constructors to set your vars
static this() {
   some_var ~= " -- How are you?";
}
```

That code was kindly provided by [Joshua Reusch](http://www.digitalmars.com/pnews/read.php?server=news.digitalmars.com&group=digitalmars.D.learn&artnum=31259) in the [excellent D forum for beginners](http://www.digitalmars.com/pnews/indexing.php?server=news.digitalmars.com&group=digitalmars.D.learn) in the digitalmars.com site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Modify your `a.d` to:

```
import std.stdio;
import b;

//extern string test ();

void main() {
  writeln(test());
  readln();
}
```

`extern` is a *linkage attribute* and is mostly used to specify what calling convention to use for the given function (typically a C function in some library). More about `extern` and other attributes here: http://www.d-programming-language.org/attribute.html . If all you have are D source files, there is really no need for extern. However, if you mix C or C++ and D code, you will definitely have to use it.